# Function firing 2000+ times

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make an inventory system and now I'm making the equipping system when the player presses the number keys but the code is firing 2000+ times when a number key is pressed.

My code at the moment is:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local inventoryFolder = Instance.new("Folder")
inventoryFolder.Name = "InventoryFolder"
inventoryFolder.Parent = player
local hotbar = script.Parent.Hotbar

for i, v in pairs(player.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
    v.Parent = inventoryFolder
    local slot = hotbar[i]
    if slot.SlotItem.Value == nil then
        slot.SlotItem.Value = v
        slot.Image = game.ReplicatedStorage[tostring(slot.SlotItem.Value)].Texture
    end
end

while wait() do
    uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(key, processed)
        if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.One then
            print(1)
        end
    end)
end
```

The key pressed script is only meant to fire once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
while wait() do
    uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(key, processed)
        if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.One then
            print(1)
        end
    end)
end
```

You keep adding callbacks here at roughly 30 callbacks per second. Get rid of the loop.